# Login Prompt not appearing on Ubuntu 20.04 login screen

Tags: boot, 20.04, login

As a disclaimer: I realise that there are a lot of questions on here that are similar to this one I haven't found one that is completely similar to my situation.

Yesterday my laptop ran out of battery during a blackout (a common occurrence in my country). Since then I'm always greeted by the following screen when trying to reboot (I've tried rebooting numerous time and this always happens):

[image: Login Screen]

This is the login screen that should show my profile after a brief load showed by a loading spinner. While the spinner did show, it dissappears and I'm not being presented with a login prompt so I'm unable to progress. Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F4 presents me with the following black screen that has a blink cursor (EDIT: I've tried multiple Ctrl + Alt + Fx combinations and nothing else works either). Unfortunately it looks like I can't type anything there (the keyboard seem to be working fine though as I'm able to use the F keys to enter bios and such).

[image: Blank screen]

I'm really not sure what do in this situation since I can't even use the console. Is this something I can remedy or am I doomed to reloading Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you use Ctrl + Alt + F5 (or any of the other F1-F7 keys) to reach a console prompt?

Comment: Unfortunately not. No keys (or combinations) seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: Assuming you run on X (rather than Wayland), you could try rebooting and choosing recovery mode from the `grub` menu, then removing the `.Xauthority` file in your home folder, and rebooting. Also, you may try to enter `startx` from there, and see if you get any meaningful error messages.